# Facebook Integration to Android App with appId

Tags: android, facebook, integration

I have downloaded the facebook android sdk and integrated to my app as mentioned in that tutorial,i generated hash key and also updated , but if i run my app through the key_id its not coming , without giving the key_id if i run it will execute , Kindly help me out pls its an emergency guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide App_ID key, otherwise it won't execute. provide your source code by that i will let you know what's the error is........

Comment: I have used the code which is given in tutorial , the link is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/  ,       If i wont give App_Id and run my build, it will open the default android browser and opens www.facebook.com, if given the app_id and run, initially for 2 secs at emulator it shows loading and show blank screen , Kindly help me out in this bug